# how to access to a hidden folder?

Tags: command-line

I want to know how to access to a hidden folder using Terminal.

I am nos asking how to make it visible.

I  have the folder home/.virtualenvs

In Terminal I tried:

```
$ cd virtualenvs and $ cd .virtualenvs
```

and I got:

```
bash: cd: virtualenvs: No such file or directory
```

How to acces from Terminal then?

thank you

Comment: In `terminal`, if you're currently at your home directory (/home/daniel) then `cd .virtualenvs` will work, as .virtualenvs is a sub-directory of /home/daniel. IF HOWEVER, the path you show is correct, then you'll need to `cd /home/.virtualenvs` to get there. Note that `/home/.virtualenvs` would not be a normal place to put the .virtualenvs directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before we start lets locate the folder:

1. `realpath virtualenvs`
2. `realpath .virtualenvs`

Now assuming you get a return of `/home/.virtualenv` from *option 2*(again assuming it was actually a *hidden folder*), then we need to move it to the proper place which aught to be in `/home/$USERNAME` or `/home/daniel` in your case.

We do so by typing this in the terminal:

```
mv /home/.virtualenvs  /home/daniel/
```

But if it returns `/home/virtualenvs`, then the folder isn't hidden and should be moved thus:

```
mv /home/virtualenvs /home/daniel/
```

**NOTE:** If not **hidden** run through the answer without the `.` before every occurrence.

Now you access *hidden folders* from the terminal like any other, except you have to add the `.` character before the name. Now in your case the fault is that you did not add the **exact location** of the `virtualenvs` folder.

Say the `virtualenvs` folder is in our `/home` directory ( as we had moved it there ) then to get at it from the terminal we will put it this way:

```
cd /home/$USERNAME/.virtualenvs
```

Now note two things here:

1. We used the *absolute path* to get to it
2. We inserted the _environmental variable `%USERNAME` into the path. We could easily have inserted or used `daniel` if that is the name Ubuntu knows you by. In which case we would have had it like this:

   ```
   cd /home/daniel/.virtualenvs
   ```

Now to see where your `virtualenvs` folder is run:

```
realpath .virtualenvs
```

This will return the *path location* of that folder which you will then use with the `cd` command to enter into it.

**Absolute and Relative Paths**:

Now let me try to explain this so you won't need to always *type /home/daniel/.virtualenvs* to get into `.virtualenvs` folder.

1. Relative Paths:

   - If I typed `pwd` and the result was `/home/daniel`. That means I am sitting or located in `/home/daniel` and when I type `realpath .virtualenvs` then also get the result `/home/daniel/.virtualenvs` then to get into `virtualenvs` ( which if you also is in `/home/daniel`) I will type:

     ```
     cd .virtualenvs
     ```
   - Now this is the **relative path**, i.e. in relation to where I currently am.
2. Absolute Paths:

   - If I don't know where I am, but know that the `.virtualenvs` folder is in the `/home/daniel` as seen when we use `realpath .virtualenvs` command. Then I will use the absolute path to get to it with:

     ```
     cd /home/daniel/.virtualenvs
     ```
   - Or if I type `pwd` to know where I was in the `filesystem` and I get a result like: `/usr/lib` then to get to .virtualenvs`the absolute path will be need as the relative path won't get me there. So from location`/usr/lib` I would type:

     ```
     cd /home/daniel/.virtualenvs
     ```

Now another important note is the use of `~/` in place of `/home/daniel`. This can be used to avoid typing the full `/home/daniel`, so for the **absolute path** to `.virtualenvs` I would have typed:

```
cd ~/.virtualenvs
```

and this would have got me there.

Comment: Need to change `.virtualenv` to `.virtualenvs` :-)

Comment: Also note that OP wasn't quite clear if the directory is at `/home/.virtualenvs` or `/home/daniel/.virtualenvs`. See my comment to the question.